# SAS Macro code error with length statement

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to change the length of the variables based on a list that I have and the code seems to work but the desired output is not achieved. here is the code:

```
%macro LEN(); 
Proc sql ; 
select count(name) into: varnum from variab; 
select name into: varname1-:varname%trim(%left(&varnum)) from Variab; 
select length3 into: len from Length; 

Quit; 


%do i=1 %to &varnum; 

    data Zero;
        length &&varname&i $ &&len&i.; 
        set desti.test;

        length _numeric_ 4.; 
        format _numeric_ 12.2;
        run; 
 %end; 
 %mend;
```

It gives a warning

```
WARNING: Multiple lengths were specified for the variable fscadl1 by     
input data set(s). This can cause truncation
     of data.
```

and it doesnt change the length of the variable. what is wrong in this code?

Comment: What is the desired output? Can you post simple input/output data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change a list of variables in *one* dataset?  You're repeating the entire data step for each iteration, but only writing to a constant destination, which is inconsistent.

Probably what you want is:

```
Proc sql ; 
select count(name) into: varnum from variab; 
select name into: varname1-:varname%trim(%left(&varnum)) from Variab; 
select length3 into: len from Length; 

Quit; 

%macro set_len(varnum=); 

%do i=1 %to &varnum; 
        length &&varname&i $ &&len&i.; 
%end;
%mend;
data Zero;
    %set_len(&varnum);
    set desti.test;

    length _numeric_ 4.; 
    format _numeric_ 12.2;
run;
```

Note that you'd need to define `&&len&i` as you're not doing that currently.

Answer (score 0):

The warning messages suggests that it is working.  SAS started throwing that warning when you truncate a variable.  You can suppress the warning message with the VARLENCHK option.

Below works:

```
options varlenchk=nowarn;
data want;
  length name $ 3;
  set sashelp.class;
  length _numeric_ 4;
run;
```

If your code isn't working, I would turn on MPRINT to see make sure your macro is generating the SAS code you expect.